# Start same thread twice - the second time after the first one finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

So I made a Thread which executes one function which is dependent on a global variable. After that, I would like to change that variable and run the thread once again, so that it executes my procedure once again with another argument. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out when my Thread finished. After a lot of googling, I found nothing that could help me. Can someone here help ? Thanks in advance. Some code would be appreciated. Here is mine:

```
//temp_folder is global variable

temp_folder = APPDATA + "Local" + "\\" + "Temp\\";

Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clean_temp));
oThread.Start();

//Here I should wait for this oThread to finish, then change the temp_folder
//variable mentioned in comment down and start once again

//temp_folder = WINDIR + "\\" + "Temp\\";
//oThread.Start();
```

Here is a clean_temp() procedure. And yes, this is GUI app.

```
public void clean_temp()
{
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(temp_folder);

try
{
    DirectoryInfo[] folders = directory.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in folders)
    {
        temp_folder = temp_folder + folder.Name + "\\";
        clean_temp();
        temp_folder = temp_folder.Replace(folder.Name + "\\", "");
    }
}
catch { }

long sz;
double size, trenutna;

foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
{
    sz = file.Length;
    size = (double)sz / 1024.0;
    trenutna = Convert.ToDouble(lbl_junk_size.Text);
    trenutna += size;

    MethodInvoker mi_invoker_size_change = new MethodInvoker(()=> lbl_junk_size.Text = trenutna.ToString());
    lbl_junk_size.Invoke(mi_invoker_size_change);

    MethodInvoker mi_invoker_count_change = new MethodInvoker(() => lbl_junk.Text = (Convert.ToInt64(lbl_junk.Text) + 1).ToString());
    lbl_junk.Invoke(mi_invoker_count_change);
}
}
```

Comment: Better use the [`ThreadPool` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) instead, IMO.

Comment: Is the main thread part of Windows GUI application? Or are you planning on doing something else while the cleanup occurs?

Comment: You could consider using a `Task`, which has a `ContinueWith` method.

Comment: Yes, it's part of Windows GUI application. It cleans temp folder and counts the files it cleared in a label.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Join()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.join(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure your thread has finished.

Eg :

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clean_temp));
oThread.Start();

oThread.Join();
```

Comment: Tried this but for some reason, my program freezes when I do this :/

Comment: It's going to freeze because Join() makes the main thread wait until the thread completes.

Comment: @DivineNeos : Could you show us your clean_temp() implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking the wrong question here. Instead of asking how to wait for a thread to finish you should look at how to perform another operation after the first finishes.

In most cases you would do this using the [Task API in .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx). Tasks give you a very clean way to define an operation that is to be performed asynchronously and then do something else when it is done.

So you could probably do something like this pseudo-code:

```
var task = new Task(clean_temp);
task.ContinueWith(update_global_variable);
task.ContinueWith(clean_temp);
task.Wait();
```

The actual code won't be exactly like this, but the idea is that you define something that should be done (call clean_temp), then you define something to be done after that first job is done (update_global_variable) and so on. You can chain as many operations you want.

This will probably be much cleaner than handling threads yourself.

EDIT:
Actually, you could probably simplify your code even more by getting rid of the global variable.

If you modify your clean_temp method to take an input argument that specifies the folder to clean then you can do the following (again, pseudocode!!!):

```
new Task(clean_temp, "C:\first temp folder")
   .ContinueWith(clean_temp, "C:\second folder")
   .Wait();
```

Much cleaner and much safer :-)

Comment: App is part of Windows GUI application. It cleans temp folder and counts the files it cleared in a label. When I wrote something like this, it freezes :S Do you know why?
var task = new Task(clean_temp);
Task task2 = task.ContinueWith((continuation) =>
{
 temp_folder = APPDATA + "Local" + "\\" + "Temp\\";
});
Task task3 = task.ContinueWith((continuation) =>
{
 clean_temp();
});
task.Wait();

Comment: Your code is quite complex (why do you do the Method.Invoke calls for instance?), so it is hard to say exactly. You should use the debugger and see what happens. Also, you have a try-catch that does nothing in the catch. You may have all kinds of errors in there as well.

Comment: Now I edited code, I wrapped my Threads in Task, it doesn't work again. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Cuz I think the problem is that it's a GUI app.

Comment: Could you post an updated code sample? The fact that it is a gui app should normally not affect anyhing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# 5, try wrapping your thread within a task. Tasks provide a method called 'ContinueWith' in which you can call your thread again. Or asynchronous calls with 'await'